# rake aborted! cannot load such file Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am trying to run a ruby file that updates the database using the rake task . But overtime I run the code, I get an error saying : 
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- app/services/insert_data

The ruby file 'insert_data' is located under the app directory in a folder named 'services'

Here is the rake task I created to run it:

```
require 'app/services/insert_data'

namespace :record_generate do


task :test do
  ruby "app/services/insert_data"
end


end
```

Please help in removing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use Rails environment within a rake task you need to declare that:

```
namespace :record_generate do    
    task :test => :environment do |_, args|
       ruby "app/services/insert_data"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try placing your `app/services/insert_data` inside the script directory. I'm assuming that your ruby file is not a rails model with logic. I would try this.

1. Get your file and place it in the `/script/` directory.
2. Place these line of code at the top of your file

   `#! /usr/bin/env ruby`

   `require_relative "../config/environment"`

Now on your command line you can do execute this:

`rails runner name_of_your_file`

That is one way of doing it. If you specifically need to use a rake task I can try posting an answer for that too.

Comment: I specifically need to use a rake task.. would be really nice if you do that

Comment: gotcha. I think either Nic or Bryce have you covered on that front. If not, I'll try my variation for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your task :test block try -

```
Rake.application.rake_require "#{Rails.root}/app/services/insert_data"
```

Comment: Now I get an error saying  rake aborted!
Can't find /Users/Desktop/platform-develop/app/services/insert_data

Comment: I would adjust to `task :test => :environment do` like Nic suggested and can you post your insert_data or show the function/method form it being called if there is a class or module in it at all?